# issue insert data in hive create small part files

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

i am processing more than 1000000 records of json file i am reading file line by line and extract requried key values 
(json are mix structure is not fix. so i am parsing and generate requried json element) and generate json string simillar to json_string variable  and push to hive table data are store properly but at hadoop apps/hive/warehouse/jsondb.myjson_table folder contain small part files. every insert query the new (.1 to .20 kb)part file will be created. beacuse of that if i run simple query on hive as it will take more than 30 min. showing sample code of my logic this iterate multipal times for new records to inesrt in hive.[image]

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSessionZipsExample").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

var json_string = """{"name":"yogesh_wagh","education":"phd" }"""

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(json_string).toDS)

//df.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("bds_data1.newversion");

df.write.mode("append").format("orc").insertInto("bds_data1.newversion");
```

i have also try to add hive property to merge the files but it wont work,

i have also try to create table from existing table for combine small part file to one 256 mb files..
please share sample code to insert multipal records and append record in part file.

Comment: Can you share code that reads more than one json object? Spark won't merge one line of json with existing files on HDFS if you are going append mode

Comment: You need to share more details about the operation. A possible issue can be your partition size but without looking at the actual operation you are performing, it would be difficult to comment precisely.

Comment: Actual data push logic is this only.  i am parsing json and get required fields and create json objects as string and try to push in hive table. the problem is only want to append to data in hadoop s part file location. by code.

Answer (score 1):

I think each of those individual inserts creating a new part file.

You could create `dataset/dataframe` of these `json` strings and then save it to hive table.

you could merge the existing small file using hive ddl `ALTER TABLE table_name CONCATENATE;`

Comment: Thanks for quick response.but i am try to do with code  i want to integrate kafka spark for real time to data push in hive table.